# How can I get a list of all people I have sent a given attachment to with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, attachment

I wish to create a contact list of all people have I send an attachment to that contains the word “CV”, how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail does not search within the contents of your attachments.

You can use the [has:attachment](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) keyword in Gmail search to find all messages that have attachments.  If "CV" was in the email itself (subject, body) then you could do `has:attachment cv`.

You cannot create a contact list by selecting emails (manually or from search results).  You have to go into your contacts, create a new group, and then add the contacts there.

Comment: thanks, how do I then create a list of all the people I send the emails to?

Comment: You can't sadly.  See my edit.